# Free program to grep unicode text files in Windows?

Tags: windows, unicode, grep

I have a collection of unicode text files (exported from regedit) and I'd like to pull out all the lines with a certain text on them.

I've tried [Grep for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) and findstr but both can't seem to handle the unicode encoding.  My results are empty, but when I use the -v option (show non-matching lines), the output shows a NUL between each character.

Are there any free options to perform a simple grep on Unicode files in Windows?

Comment: Use find, not findstr.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just ran across [grepWin](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/grepWin.html) which works perfectly for what I want here.  Wish I would have found it earlier!

Answer (score 10):

Well, while `findstr` can't handle Unicode files directly, `type` does and `findstr` actually handles Unicode *input* without problems.

So what you need to do would just be

```
type myfile.txt | findstr /c:"I'm searching for this"
```

```
> type uc-test.txt
Unicode test. äöüß
Another line
Something else
> findstr "Something" uc-test.txt

> findstr /v "Something" uc-test.txt
 ■U n i c o d e   t e s t .   õ ÷ ³ ▀
 A n o t h e r   l i n e
 S o m e t h i n g   e l s e
> type uc-test.txt | findstr "Another"
Another line
```

Comment: I've had no problem with findstr and unicode. Seems to work fine. Also ought to add that you can search with regular expressions by passing in the /r switch. Like grep it also has ignore case, and list files only etc etc.

Comment: this works for a single file -- still looking for a grep replacement so that I can pick out a single line from each of many files, each in their own subdirectory

Comment: You can easily combine this with `for /r` to walk a directory tree recursively.

Comment: Thank you, I did get this working: `FOR /R %%D IN (*.txt) do type "%%d" | findstr /c:"Search text" >> outFile.txt`  (Now I'd love to figure out a way to prefix each line with the name and/or timestamp of the file it was in, similar to the default behavior of grep.)

Comment: emacs 23 has unicode support, and a nice search system

Comment: The first example is slightly misleading by demonstrating a common misunderstanding of findstr:

`type myfile.txt | findstr "I'm searching for this"`

...will actually search for I'm OR searching OR for OR this -- any of the four space separated words.

`type myfile.txt | findstr /C:"I'm searching for this"`

...searches for the literal phrase.  

This feature is very convenient or somewhat annoying depending on your level of experience with findstr.

Comment: @HerbM, simply editing the answer would have been faster ... ;-)

Comment: @Joey Sorry, didn't know that was polite or proper. Will do.

Comment: @HerbM: For factually incorrect things I'd always edit unless the answer is fresh and may still be edited by the author. Granted, acceptance of edits varies, though, and some do absolutely not like it.

Answer (score 3):

definitely go with cygwin (using x server) - the latest supports utf8.  At my last gig, I was doing a lot of work with CJK characters.  Using cygwin's x server, you can search on any characters and display any characters that you have a fixed width font for.  Also check out od and xxd which makes it easy to enter your searches using hex characters eg:
$ echo '?' | grep $(echo '3f' | xxd -p -r)

Comment: I'm a big proponent of Cygwin, and I think its GREP would probably do well with UTF-8 input. But I can tell you that even the latest versions of Cygwin GREP can't deal effectively with UCS-16. I don't blame Cygwin so much as I blame the "let's encode all characters as 16-bit units" mentality that gave us UCS-16. Gee, a new architectural wrinkle that's neither adequate for what it's trying to accomplish *nor* compatible with any existing code at all! Thanks, 1991!

Answer (score 3):

If you have notepad++, you can use "Find in Files..." option to search unicode files.

Comment: Very helpful - I *always* have Notepad++...

Answer (score 2):

I use grep.exe from http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ with "chcp 65001" command conjunction in the Windows command line.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used windows for years, but I know two alternatives to grep which are written in interpreted language and therefore should run on any platform:

- [ack-grep](http://betterthangrep.com/) (in perl)
- [grin](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/grin) (in python)

Both are command-line tool, but I assume you already have a solution for this if you have used grep for windows.

Have a look at them, I am sorry I can't help a fellow grepper better than this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dnGREP](http://code.google.com/p/dngrep/). It's another open source grep tool which supports unicode file type.

Answer (score 0):

is cygwin an option for you? maybe the grep that is builtin behaves better than the one you tried...

regards

Comment: Unfortunately, that has not been my observation. I'm dealing with this issue, and Cygwin GREP was the first thing I tried. Both Cygwin GREP and UnxUtils GREP seem only to find results if I convert the files to ASCII (or at least to UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

check out [BareGrep](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baregrep/). I think it will do what you want.

Comment: Pretty cool program but doesn't seem to work with unicode text -- am I missing something?

Comment: I personally have not tired it with Unicode, but their sales propaganda says it will. they could (and probably are), of course, be lying.

Comment: It does not handle UTF16 files (I own the pro version), and was looking for a replacement tool when I hit this page.

Answer (score 0):

perl -CSD -ne 'print if m{\Qyour text here\E}' file.txt

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most convient free program you need in Windows is Powershell. For example:

Get-ChildItem  -Recurse -path c:\temp\*.c |Select-String -pattern "myunicodestring"

Or if you just only want to search in a directory (not in subdirectory):

Select-String -path "c:\mydir\*.log" -pattern "error"