# In Windows, how do I find all files in a certain directory that are encoded using unicode?

Tags: windows, search, unicode, command-line

I am having trouble searching a large directory of files for a string.  The search command I'm using is skipping any file encoded in Unicode.  I want to find all the files in this directory that are encoded in Unicode.  I am on Windows XP.

Thank you!

Comment: What search command are you using?  Is it skipping the files (i.e. not searching them), or searching them but not finding the string in them? i.e. you know it's in a particular file but it's not reporting it.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196883/free-program-to-grep-unicode-text-files-in-windows and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063049/search-for-unicode-text-inside-windows-xp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't know encoding before you open a file and read from it. So you will enumerate directory files, then go through the list, open and check either `BOM` or the content itself (such as certain amount of heading bytes).

Answer (score 0):

The `find` command in Windows supports Unicode text files.  `findstr` doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with my script below, the input does not care what encoding, as far as you specify the output encoding like this `-Encoding ASCII`.

1. Goto the Dir you want `cd c:\MyDirectoryWithCrazyCharacterEncodingAndUnicode`
2. Fire this script away!

Copy and past the script in your Powershell windows, you get the idea just play with it to fix the syntax

```
 foreach($FileNameInUnicodeOrWhatever in get-childitem )
 {        
    $tempEncoding = (Get-Content -encoding byte)
    write-output $FileNameInUnicodeOrWhatever "has encoding" $tempEncoding   

    //  [System.Text.Encoding]::$result
 }
```

If you want to further resolve issues with not being able to find files because of encoding, [change the encoding type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887398/how-to-bulk-convert-unicode-file-names-to-ascii-file-names-windows-cmd-or-powers/41889138#41889138)